# Writing $ M-N $ proof and assuming monotonicity

Tags: limits

In the following proof, aren't we assuming that $ \sqrt{x}$ is monotonically increasing?

$ a_n = \sqrt{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $

$ \lim{n \to \infty} \, a_n = \infty $

Given $ M \gt 0 $, Choose $ N = M^2 $

For all  $ n \gt N  $, $ n \gt M^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{n} \gt M  $

$ \forall M \gt 0 \exists N\left(n \gt N \Rightarrow a_n \gt M\right) $

Comment: No. We are assuming that the square root function is monotonically increasing.